# Python: running without errors

Tags: python

Below is a statement to be executed in the shell. Write Python statements to go before
it that will guarantee that the statement will run without error. It doesn't matter what the code does, just that it runs. Below is an example.
Code:
a = p(b % c)

Statements to go before this one to guarantee that it will run without error:

```
def p(n):
    return n + 1
b = 45
c = 13
```

---

Code:

```
n = d[x](96) + 7
```

Statements to go before this one to guarantee that it will run without error:

```
def hello(n):
    return n + 5
d = {1:hello}
x = 1
```

I don't get the code. How can there be a square bracket, [x], with a parenthesis, (96), together to get a value in the dictionary d? What does that mean? Also, how come "hello" does not have quotes around the word since it is a string? I just don't get the code overall.

Comment: `hello` is a function not a string. 1 is the key in the dictionary which has a value of the `function` `hello`. Dictionary values can be anything and keys don't have to be strings.

Comment: I can't speak for others, but they may not like your question because it looks like you've copied it directly from your homework (if not, maybe you should be _writing_ homework questions). The question might be a little easier to understand (for us) if you leave out the first part / add some explanation around the second part...

Answer (score 7):

Since `d` is a dictionary, so accessing any element inside it requires you to use a `index` number, in the shown code, it is `x`. So, `d[x]` accesses the element at index `x` of dictionary.

When the defining of d is done, there is `d = { 1:hello}` this means that the `1th` index of dictionary is referring to the predefined function named `hello` hence, during the call, there is a parenthesis used in the following line:

```
n = d[x](96) + 7
```

Since, we set `x = 1`, therefor, the call will actually be parsed as follows:

```
# d[x] calls dictionary element at index x
# x = 1, therefore, d[x] => d[1]
# d[1] is function hello
# d[1](96) will pass number 96 to function hello.
```

Answer (score 2):

`a = p(b % c)`

`a` is the name of the value returned by `p`. `p` is a function name ie `def p(args): pass`, `(b % c)` is the argument being fed to the `p` function, which finds the remainder from the division: `b/c` and passes that to `p`.

`n = d[x](96) + 7`

`n` is the name of the value returned by the value of the entry. `d` could be a list or a dict. `[x]` is the index of the item that is retrieved. `(96)` is the argument you're passing to the item returned from the function in `d` at index `x`. `+7` is added to the object returned from the function `d[x]` with the argument `96`.

Hopefully this will be a good starting point for you to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your reply was helpful.

Comment: My pleasure. You seem to be asking a few questions here about your homework though. Part of python/coding is working out your own questions and just googling them. It's probably time for you to look up basic python tutorials, and just follow through them; it's easier than typing up questions for each assignment you've got due.